# Volume of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gr.group-theory, lie-groups

So according to http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/v/SL2C.pdf
I can write the Haar measure of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ as
$$d\mu = \sinh^2(r) dr dk dk'$$
where $r$ runs over nonnegative real numbers and $k,k' \in SU(2)$.
Does this mean that I can decompose the volume of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ as 
volume of $S^3$ times some infinite residual volume? Namely,
$$\rm{vol} SL(2,\mathbb{C})= \rm{vol} S^3\times vol_R$$
where $\rm vol_R = \int_0^\infty \sinh^2(r)dr$?

---

$\mathbf{Update}$:
I have a path integral of the form 
$$ Z= \int_M\frac{d\mu}{{\rm vol}G}\exp\left[-\int_{S^1} dt{L[\phi(t),d\phi(t)/dt,d^2\phi(t)/dt^2]}\right]. $$
where $G=SL(2,\mathbb{C})$, $t\in [-\pi,\pi]$ parametrizes a circle and $\phi(t)$ is a complex-valued periodic function with possible singularities for some values of $t$, defined on a non-compact space of $M=\rm{Diff}(S^1)_\mathbb{C}$ and finally $L$ is a functional of $\phi$ and its derivatives. Now the path integral here diverges like $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\exp\log[\sinh(\epsilon)]$ and I need to cancel that divergence with the volume of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ in the manner I explained above.

Thank you,

AB

Comment: What does it mean to ask whether two infinite measures are equal?

Comment: For every choice of left Haar measure on a non-compact locally compact group, the volume is infinite. Indeed, for every compact neighborhood $K$ of 1, there exists an infinite sequence of pairwise disjoint left translates of $K$ and since $K$ has positive measure it follows that the total volume is $\infty$.

Comment: @LSpice Since I am taking a space and moding out a SL(2,C), I need to see how volumes cancel out. So I need to know what this infinite volume is made of.